# iOS - Overusing memory causing crash while converting PDF to image

Tags: ios, swift, ram

This is what I'm trying to achieve: after the user picks some PDF documents in UIDocumentPickerViewController, convert each page of a document into an UIImage, save that UIImage to the disk and store its file url in an `imageUrls` array. After all documents are converted, I will pass the `imageUrls` array to my next ViewController.

The following code is working, but it causes a dramatic increase of usage of the memory (RAM): my app uses 92MB memory before converting, and it can use up to **550MB** when I try to convert a merely 25MB PDF document. While this runs in my simulator, but it's causing some crashes on my user's iPhone XR. I'm guessing the reason is the overuse of memory.

Below is my code doing the conversion, if anyone can help me to identify where the issue is, it will be really appreciated.

```swift
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        print("Import result: \(urls)"). // urls look like this [file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../my-document.pdf]
        
        let group = DispatchGroup() // use group to monitor the completion of converting all picked PDF documents
        var imageUrls = [URL]()  // the URL array to pass to the next ViewController

        for (docIndex, url) in urls.enumerated() {
            group.enter()
            // do conversion on global queue so UI is not blocked
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                guard let pdfDocument = createPDFdocumentFromUrl(url) else { return } // helper method 1: createPDFdocumentFromUrl(_:URL)
                SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Converting PDF \(docIndex + 1)") // show a spinner

                for page in (1...pdfDocument.numberOfPages) {
                    guard let image = pdfDocument.drawPage(page),  // helper method 2: CGPDFDocument.drawPage(_:Int)
                        let imageUrl = image.saveToDisk(fileName: "drawing-\(docIndex)-\(page).jpg") // helper method 3: UIImage.saveToDisk(fileName: String)
                        else { continue }
                    imageUrls.append(imageUrl)
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss() // dismiss spinner
            print("Pass imageUrls array to next ViewController")
        }
}
```

And here are the 3 helper methods I used in code above:

```swift
// helper method 1
func createPDFdocumentFromUrl(_ url: URL) -> CGPDFDocument? {
    CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) ?? nil
}

extension CGPDFDocument {
    // helper method 2: convert the specified PDF page into UIImage
    func drawPage(_ page: Int) -> UIImage? {
        guard let page = self.page(at: page) else { return nil }
        
        let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            UIColor.white.set()
            ctx.fill(pageRect)

            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
            ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

            ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
        }

        return img
    }
}


extension UIImage {
    /// helper method 3: save image in `/www` folder
    func saveToDisk(fileName: String) -> URL? {
        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
        let wwwFolderUrl = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("www")
        let fileURL = wwwFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        guard let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return nil }
        
        //Checks if file exists, removes it if so.
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
                print("Removed old image")
            } catch let removeError {
                print("couldn't remove file at path", removeError)
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch let error {
            print("error saving file with error", error)
            return nil
        }
        
        return fileURL
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what function is allocating all that memory it will be very hard to know how to resolve this issue.  Have you tried using Instruments to figure out what data types are being created and where, to narrow down your focus?

That said, a simple thing to try would be to wrap the contents of your `for page in (1...pdfDocument.numberOfPages)` loop in an `autoreleasepool`.  Without it, many objects that fall out of scope at the end of one iteration will not be freed until every page is processed.

Comment: @JamieA Thanks for the `autoreleasepool` suggestion, I did a little google search and ended up wrapping my loop's content in `autoreleasepool`, and the memory efficiency is largely improved on my simulator. I will also let my users to try on the real devices.